# Possible to separate out a web application to multiple machines with different purposes, sharing the same session?

Tags: .net, oracle, session, iis, shared

I am looking for suggestions, help, or a "you cannot do that" answer if you can help.

I am on a .NET development team using .NET 4.0 and running a web app that is in MVP.  Right now, we have a web farm of 4 IIS boxes running Win2K3 and IIS 6 (upgrading next year) and an F5 BigIP device is using sticky session to span traffic across all four boxes.  And our application is expanding in size and scope due to its success. That is a nice problem to have I assure you. However we are experiencing growing pains. And we are looking to keep the transactional work (add/edit/delete through various web forms) on the 4 machines currently in use, and then add 2 other machines JUST for the workload of reporting/metrics.

Here is what we want to do:

1. Put session state in our Oracle database using the Oracle.Web.dll object classes available for this, and running the .SQL files against our Oracle 11g DB to get the session setup right. So if one box dies the session data persists.
2. Setup our web.config to use the Oracle database for our session provider across all 4 current boxes.

So far so good. That is fairly basic and repeatable.  No worries. Here is where I am getting stuck:

1. We want to pull out the reporting ASPX files for this application and put them on 2 different (new) IIS boxes (now a total of 6), with the F5 BigIP doing load balancing on just those two for reporting with a sticky session in use. And leaving the other 4 for the OLTP transactional work in tact w/o reporting.
2. Somehow, some way we would like to use the same session store we created above to attach to for the 2 IIS boxes running just the reporting mechanisms, tracking a user's session and not having to repeat a login/authentication/authorize and fill the security class with their user rights for running reports. The reporting is part of the application, however it would only handle the reporting pieces and only that code would be put onto the 2 new machines. It can operate independently IF the the current user's session is still active, valid, and we can get to it.

It is almost as if we are wanting a distributed application structure with different IIS servers running different parts of the web application, but sharing the session state.

Has anyone come across something like this? Is this possible or not possible? Or is there a better alternative? Thank you for whatever you can help with.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this.  You have to give each application the same [machineKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). Start here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527105 and here: [simple bing query](http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net%20share%20session&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=asp.net%20share%20session&sc=5-17&sp=-1&sk=)

Comment: All 4 machines have the same machine key, so I can make sure the remaining 2 that we add will have the same machine key as well. Much obliged! Perfect first link. And now I know what to search on with the Bing query. Thank you much!

Comment: I just got this implemented and it worked well. I had to run the aspnet_regsql –ssadd –sstype p –E  -S localhost\sqlexpress so the asp session state is persistent because of who the customer is and what they allow. Other than that it worked like a charm!  I can do a job to clean up session state later if I do not want it for auditing purposes.